# How would i display a message if mysql doesn't return a result or empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

how would i get this to display a message in place of the Query if no result is found i updated the code but its just showing "N"

```
<?php

$hostname = "...";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";

$dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
$query=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT DISTINCT companyname,client_id,feedback,status from review WHERE status=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
$rows_get = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rows_get >0)
{
$query2=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT DISTINCT companyname,client_id,feedback,status from review WHERE status=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
   $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
   $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
   $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
   $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
   $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);

}else {
   $row1 = "N0 Data";
   $row2 = "N0 Data";
   $row3 = "N0 Data";
   $row4 = "N0 Data";
   $row5 = "N0 Data";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use a conditional statement on [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead of what you have now.

Comment: i tried and it just bugs out

Comment: I can't see it failing; see what the answer holds below. That's how it's done. If that didn't work, then you'll have to tell them.

Comment: ya i'll have to see why i'm still new to mysql and php so i'm like scratching my head over this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:
 After $query insert this:

```
$rows_get = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rows_get >0)
{
//do all database operation
}else {
 echo " No data found";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Amend your code for example..

```
if ($row_get>0){
//i assume you are getting multiple rows
 while ($data =mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query))
{
//run this loop and you will get all you rows.
}
}
```

Comment: i'm just getting this [link](https://gyazo.com/4c4bcf6f2d6bfe9792bc37ae026d7dd5) i updated the code at the top i'm also useing a few different variables <?php echo $row1['client_id'];  ?> <?php echo $row1['feedback'];  ?> and <?php echo $row1['companyname'];  ?>

Comment: No you are doing it wrong.  No need to run the query again in if else clause. Also do you getting single row or multiple rows from your query. Explain so that we can answer your queries.

Comment: do you have discord or something i'm just confused i have another post on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426712/if-else-not-showing-results-correctly